# How to store objects in an array to be used later?

Tags: java, arrays

I was curious how to store java objects in an array. I am confused, because my teacher does not know himself, and we have not gone over object arrays, only arrays and objects separately.

My code looks like such:

```
public class SongDriver
    {
    public static void main( String[] args )
        {
        Song a = new Song();
        a.title = "Freebird";
        a.artist = "Lynyrd Skynryd";

        Song b = new Song();
        b.title = "Sweet Home Alabama";
        b.artist = "Lynyrd Skynryd";

        Song c = new Song();
        c.title = "Black or White";
        c.artist = "Michael Jackson";

        Song d = new Song();
        d.title = "Smooth Criminal";
        d.artist = "Michael Jackson";

        }
    }
```

This is exactly how my objects are supposed to be according to the teacher.

My other class called song is:

```
public class Song
    {
    String title;
    String artist; 
    }
```

I was trying things such as String myPod = new Song[4];
.. But nothing is working, and my knowledge is basic.

Comment: "because my teacher does not know himself..." ._.

Comment: +1 for "my knowledge is BASIC"

Comment: @DennisMeng He admits he doesn't know much java.. and I spent 10 minutes in class today explaining a program that generated fibonaccis numbers to him.

Comment: @scottb Hard to tell if that is sarcastic.. But surprisingly I am the top of my class. I am not sure many are on track for passing the AP exam for computer science atm..

Comment: @Garzhod: No sarcasm.  I thought it was a cute pun.

Comment: @Garzhod That's unfortunate. At least you are making an honest effort to learn though; it's nice to see someone who's actually trying to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array is a defined container of a given type, for example...

```
{type}[] {variable};
```

So, based on the fact that you are trying to create an array of `Song`, you need to define the array as a type of `Song`, for example...

```
Song[] songs;
```

Of course, you should also initialise it, so based on your example, you could use something like...

```
Song[] songs = new Song[4];
songs[0] = new Song();
songs[0].title = "Freebird";
songs[0].artist = "Lynyrd Skynryd";

songs[1] = new Song();
songs[1].title = "Sweet Home Alabama";
songs[1].artist = "Lynyrd Skynryd";

songs[2] = new Song();
songs[2].title = "Black or White";
songs[2].artist = "Michael Jackson";

songs[3] = new Song();
songs[3].title = "Smooth Criminal";
songs[3].artist = "Michael Jackson";
```

Remember, an array is a fixed length container.  It can only contain up to the number of elements you specify.

You can also assign values to an element, for example...

```
Song a = new Song();
a.title = "Freebird";
a.artist = "Lynyrd Skynryd";

songs[0] = a;
```

Which would be the same as using...

```
Song a = new Song();
songs[0] = a;
songs[0].title = "Freebird";
songs[0].artist = "Lynyrd Skynryd";
```

or

```
songs[0] = new Song();
songs[0].title = "Freebird";
songs[0].artist = "Lynyrd Skynryd";
```

The `0` element shares the same reference as `a`, so changing the properties of either `a` or `songs[0]` would effect the same object, until either reference was changed...

You can find out more by having a read through the [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) trail...

Comment: This would work, but my teacher wanted us to create objects first, then add them to an array. This will work in a pinch.. but any way to adjust it?

Comment: What do you mean by "adjust it"?

Comment: As in, have the objects like I did in my original post, and create an array to include those objects? Instead of making the objects an array?

Comment: When I use the first method, I get "variable songs might not have been initialized". I did just email my teacher asking him how he would like it done, as the class I am taking, Ap Computer Science A, is brand new at my high school. I am planning to use the third example in the edited code, or the original. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Silly me, I read it wrong. New code is: Song[] songs = new Song[4];
        songs[0] = a;
        songs[1] = b;
        songs[2] = c;
        songs[3] = d;                                                                It looks like it will work. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use ArrayList to store objects in an array.

```
ArrayList<Song> arraySong = new ArrayList<Song>();
```

That will create an arraylist of Song object (but with no element currently)

```
Song a = new Song();
a.title = "Freebird"
a.artist = "Lynyrd Skynryd"
arraySong.add(a);
```

now the arraylist arraySong has one Song object. and you can do the same for the rest of the Song objects.

Comment: We have not been taught Array Lists yet, so my teacher will not want me to use them. As a side note, do you have a source where I could learn about them?

Comment: @Garzhod Check out the [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) trail

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you! You have been very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an array unless you can know or derive the number of elements at compile time.

A collection of album tracks is a collection, so I'd use a Collection.  Because there is no natural association between an album track and an index, I would use a Set rather than an ArrayList (but you could also use an ArrayList).

If you wrote your Song class to honor the equals() contract and to have a usable hashcode() function (... write your Song class to be immutable, too), then it would be convenient to represent your data as:

```
Set<Song> mySongs = new HashSet<>();
```

Even better than this, though, is to create a normalized set of data tables and put this data into a database via JDBC (with Song as your data model object).  That would also take care of persistence for you.

Comment: My teacher specifically asked for an array. This is still the early weeks of a java course, with no previous experience. I will check out your method though and gleam what I can from it. Thank you for the answer!